# Switching Scenes with several FXML files

Tags: java, javafx

I am new to Java FX and trying to build up an "easy" application which consists of a header button bar and a "content area" below.
I've managed a big part like that:

- MainWindow.fxml with a Borderpane: MenuBar in the Top Area
  And a Pane with `fx:id: content` in the center area.
- Several X.fxml files for the content ()
- One Controller which creates the obj content:

  ```
  @FXML
  private Pane content;
  ```

  and switches the content:

  ```
  content.getChildren().clear();
  content.getChildren().add(FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Navi.fxml")));`
  ```
- Main file which initializes the parent and scene:

  ```
  Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("MainWindow.fxml"));
  Stage Window = primaryStage;
  Scene scene = new Scene(root);
  scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
  Window.setTitle("ICIS - In Car Interactive System");
  Window.setScene(scene);
  Window.show();`
  ```

So far everything works fine!
But now I want to apply a  `SplitPane` and do the "content change" in each side of the Split Pane (TwoWindows.fxml): So I've extended the

- Controller with obj. for every Pane of the Split Pane, assigned the fx:id to that pane and want to control them analog to the example before.

  ```
  @FXML
  private Pane SecondWindow1;
  SecondWindow1.getChildren().add(FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Navi.fxml")));
  ```

Well, during compilation everything is fine, but while running I get the Null error exception, so that I assume `SecondWindow1` (left half of SlitPane) is not known to the controller.
I also assume, it is because I initialize at the beginning only MainWindow.fxml (which includes the content area) but not the TwoWindows.fxml (SplitPane) which inlcude the SecondWindow1 Object.

Well I've tried since hours now to solve it, but apparently I am overlooking sth. Somebody knows how to fix that problem? Do I need one Controller for every FXML File?

Comment: You do have a different controller for every FXML file, unless you are doing something very unusual. You probably mean "Should the controller for each FXML file be from a different class?"; yes, you should define different classes for the controllers of each FXML file.

Comment: Ok, but I think this still won't solve my problem. When is the fxml structure known to the instance of Controller? I guess it is after Loading it the first time with the FXMLLoader, right? So is there a possibilty to load all the FXML files in the startup, so that their elements are known before using them?

Comment: I don't really understand that comment. `@FXML`-annotated fields are initialized in the controller instance during the `FXMLLoader`'s `load()` method. You create a different controller class for each FXML file. Each controller is only responsible for managing the components defined in the hierarchy loaded from its corresponding FXML file. Why would you need to preload FXML files?